# Send struct with double pointer to struct over network

Tags: c, unix, struct, deep-copy

Send struct with double pointer to struct over networkI have to send this huge structure that represents the directory structure over network. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int count;
    dir **subdir;
}dir;
```

I have to send this over network, which means I need to make a deep copy of this in a buffer and send it over TCP. I am pretty new to c and do not know how to make the copy of this whole hierarchy and especially how to reconstruct this on the other end. I am clear on how to handle network part. Please help.

Comment: It needs to be _serialized_.  That means you create a format by which the data can be completely recovered.  With this structure there is no reason why you would need to fill a buffer before sending.  You could just deliver chunks on-the-fly while doing a depth-first traversal of the structure.  I am struggling to understand how you are having trouble with this idea when you can happily code networking logic in C.

Comment: Well, I've a framework in place to send and recv data. I am having difficulty in trying to understand how to deserialze data on the receiving end.

Comment: You do the opposite of serializing, of course.  If you have serialized your data, then perhaps you should show how you have done it.

Comment: [No need to invent it yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats), try protocol buffers or avro.

Comment: It's curious that you have `int *name`.  You'll need to know how long that array is, and send it over the wire one item at a time, with either a length before or an end indication after the data.  (Note that C strings use an end indicator — a null byte.)  The acronym that's often used TLV: type, length, value.  Similarly with your matrix of directories — if that's what the `dir **subdir` represents; you'll need to encode the type of data that follows, with some way to tell when you've sent it all (either an up-front count or an end-of-data marker).  Pointers can't usefully be sent directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can not send a pointer over the network because it is not real data. You need to send the real data that the pointer points to. On the sender's computer, you need a serialization method that converts the whole struct to a byte array and passes this byte array to the transmission framework (or TCP/IP stack).

On the other side (the receiver's computer), you need a de-serialization method that converts the received byte array to the original struct. In your case, I suggest that you study `json-c`, it will help. Serialize the whole struct by looping over every entry in `dir` and convert into a JSON string. It's quite easy because `json-c` will do the whole thing for you.